# Add custom css for react dropdown tree select all other css mashup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dropdown-tree-select

In my project I have installed dropdown tree select and I want to use custom css for this. However, if I add a new rule in my webpack config,  the plugin works fine but all other css is mashed up.

And if i remove the rule than all other css works fine but this dropdown tree select doesn't work properly.

react dropdown tree select with country flag so in that case i have to add some custom css.

below is my webpack config. So can you tell me which rule I have to add/remove in my webpack config?

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
        {
            loader: 'css-loader'
        }
        ]
    }),
    include: /node_modules[/\\]react-dropdown-tree-select/
    },

    // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
    // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
    // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
    // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
    // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
    {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        require.resolve('style-loader'),
        {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules:true,
            localIdentName:'[Name]__[local]__[has:base64:5]'
        },
        },
        {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
            // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
            // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                ],
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
            }),
            ],
        },
        },
    ],
    }, 


    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
```

Answer (score 1):

`react-dropdown-tree-select` author here.

In order to use your own css on top of the component's css, you need to have 2 rules in your webpack - one for importing the component styles, and the other for importing your styles.

This is true in general for any react component that comes with styles. The component styles are pre-compiled, so you need to tell webpack to not run any further processing on it.

```
{
    test: /.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader'
        }]
    }),
    include: /node_modules[/\]react-dropdown-tree-select/
}, {
    test: /.css$/,
    // rest of your rule goes here
    include: ['src']  // or 'lib' or whatever folder your styles reside in
}
```

The first rule matches the component css via this condition `include: /node_modules[/\]react-dropdown-tree-select/` and since we don't need to run any post processing on it, we simply include it via css-loader.

The second rule matches styles in your source code via `include: ['src']` condition and allows you to apply whatever loaders you wish to run.

Looking at your OP, I think you're missing the `include` on your 2nd rule and thus, it gets applied to node modules as well. Trying filtering it and let me know if that solves your problem.

Lastly, I'll just leave this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w41wlvj8z) that shows how to include custom css with country flags here, in case you have seen it or future readers who may come looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

a solution without webpack. Only scss. played with the colors.

```js
import DropdownTreeSelect from "react-dropdown-tree-select";
import "./data.scss";
import data from "./data.json";

......

onChange = (currentNode, selectedNodes) => {
  console.log("path::", currentNode.path);
};

assignObjectPaths = (obj, stack) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    const node = obj[k];
    if (typeof node === "object") {
      node.path = stack ? `${stack}.${k}` : k;
      this.assignObjectPaths(node, node.path);
    }
  });
};

render() {
  this.assignObjectPaths(data);
  return ( 
   <div>
    <DropdownTreeSelect 
      data = { data }
      clearSearchOnChange = {true}
      placeholderText = "Select"
      showPartiallySelected = { true }
      onChange = { this.onChange }
      className = "mdl-demo" 
    />
   </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/**

div.react-dropdown-tree-select
  div.dropdown
    a.dropdown-trigger
      span
    ul.tag-list
      li.tag-item
        input
    div.dropdown-content
      ul.root
        li.node.tree
          i.toggle.collapsed
          label
            input.checkbox-item
              span.node-label
*/


/* fallback, until https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/174 is resolved */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v36/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format("woff2");
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.mdl-demo {
  .dropdown-trigger>span:after {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: gold;
  }
  .toggle {
    font: normal normal normal 18px/1 "Material Icons";
    color: blue;
    white-space: pre;
    margin-right: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle:after {
    content: "";
  }
  .toggle.collapsed::after {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "\E5CF";
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
  }
  .toggle.expanded::after {
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "\E5CE";
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
  }
  /* checkbox styles */
  .checkbox-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .checkbox-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid lawngreen;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .checkbox-item:checked:before {
    height: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-color: #2196f3;
  }
  .tag {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .tag-remove {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  .tag-remove.readOnly {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .node>label {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .tag-list {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .tag-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
  }
  .tag-item .search {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    outline: none;
  }
  .tag-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .node {
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .node.leaf.collapsed {
    display: none;
  }
  .node.disabled>* {
    color: lightseagreen;
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .node.match-in-children.hide .node-label {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .searchModeOn .toggle {
    // display: none;
  }
  .checkbox-item.simple-select {
    // display: none;
  }
  .hide:not(.match-in-children) {
    //display: none;
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger {
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 20px;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 3px solid brown;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger.arrow.bottom:after {
    content: "\25BC";
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: pink;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger.arrow.top:after {
    content: "\25B2";
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: limegreen;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger.arrow.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-trigger.arrow.disabled.bottom:after {
    color: orangered;
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: lightskyblue;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown-content ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.special {
  color: green;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<!--
demo data.json

[
    {
      "label": "VP Accounting",
      "tagClassName": "special",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "iWay",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Universidad de Especialidades del Espíritu Santo"
            },
            {
              "label": "Marmara University"
            },
            {
              "label": "Baghdad College of Pharmacy"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
-->
```